# add GeoDjango dependencies on alpine docker

Tags: django, docker, gdal, alpine-linux, geodjango

I want to use GeoDjango on alpine docker and should add some dependencies on docker to use postgis database, refers to Django [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) I have to install by
`$ sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin`
I found that `gdal` and `gdal-dev` have already existed on alpine, so I used `RUN apk add gdal gdal-dev` but after running this `docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate --noinput` Django says that :

```
'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

How to add GeoDjango dependencies on alpine dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install `geos-dev` library too for that.